# Prove that $b^2=a^2$

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $G$ be a group of order $8$. Assume that there exists $a \in G$ such that $\lvert a\rvert =4$ and that no elements of $G$ has order $8$. Assume  $\langle a \rangle \lhd G$, $b \notin \langle a\rangle$ and $b^2 \in \langle a\rangle$. Suppose that $\lvert b\rvert=4$, then Prove that $b^2=a^2$.

Not sure how to do it. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $b\in \langle a\rangle$ then $b^{2}=a^{k}$ for some $0\leq k\leq 3$. But we know $|b|=4$ then $b^{2}$ has order 2. You can check that the only element of order 2 in $\langle a\rangle$ is $a^{2}$. Hence $b^{2}=a^{2}$. Ι do not see where the hypotheses that $\langle a\rangle \triangleleft G$ and $b\notin \langle a\rangle$ are required though.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: If $|b|=4$ then $|b^2|=...$. We know that $b^2 \in \langle a \rangle$. What element of $\langle a \rangle$ has the same order as $b^2$?

Comment: $|b^2| = 2$. And $|a^2| = 2$.

Comment: @NadiaC: And $a^2$ is the only element of order 2 in $\langle a \rangle$.

Comment: Make sense. Thanks.